# wait() in semaphores is Atomic

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

I am new to OS.This question might sound a little dumb, but please help me to understand the concept behind it.
Let S-> A semaphore variable
Now let wait(S) be implemented as

```
wait(S){
  while S<=0 ;
  S--;

}
```

Now wait(S) is an atomic operation.Atomic means it cannot be interrupted.
Now if I have a uniprocessor then the Process executing wait() will run forever and will never be preempted if some other process sets S=0.
How does it work out? Please Explain.

Comment: sheduler dont allow one thread to take a core for infinite time, it works on time slicing, the therad you are thinking will go in infinite loop only get say 100 ns for execution then other thread take controll on core? got it ?

Comment: But what then atomic means.

Comment: atomic means either your "logical operation" will complete or fail ... according to your question its correct it cant  be interupted but on sheduler level i.e. "technical operation" can be sliced in time slots .. its little hard to understand but dont confuse between logical and technical operations ..

Comment: Semaphore waits are NOT implemented in such a crude fashion, no matter how many CPU/cores have access to the semaphore.  Execution is removed from waiting threads.

Comment: 'let wait(S) be implemented as a polling loop' is about as sane as 'let the hammer be implemented with a saw'.